# JQuery Mobile ajaxEnabled + asp.net form postbackurl = issues

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-mobile, postback

I'm having troubles with a jquery mobile webpage made with asp.net. The postbacks on pages that are not the first page visited does not work, since they are loaded with ajax - and the "action" of the form tag is not updated.

I have set data-ajax="false" on the form tag.

I update the "action" attribute on the form with JS, but that is not accepted by asp.net in postbacks: "Validation of viewstate MAC failed". A made a workaround on this error by setting 
this in web.config: 
    pages enableViewStateMac="false" enableEventValidation="false"
Now I can postback to correct page with no errors.

BUT, the page I'm postbacking on does not catch the postback. I see that the form data is submitted, but the method in code behind is not triggered. Works fine if the page is not ajax-loaded.

Comment: I am having a similar issue too! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649487/form-will-not-submit

Comment: your question has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

try looking at jQuerys .live() function. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

Try to place your form tags (open and close) just before and just after the content div... then you can use data-ajax=true and have the fancy animations...